# Functions looping error statements multiple times

Tags: c, function

I wrote a function 'getInt' to display an error if a user does not enter a valid integer (ex. 2abc), but the function instead will output an error for every invalid value.It only does this when there are 3 or more invalid values. For instance 2ab would be fine and only one error message would display, but 2abc would present 3 error messages. Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//tools
void welcome(void);
void printTitle(void);
void printFooter(double gTotal);
void flushKeyboard(void);
void pause(void);
int getInt(void);
double getDouble(void);
int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit);
double getDoubleLimited(double lowerLimit, double upperLimit);

//app interface
int yes(void);
void GroceryInventorySystem(void);
int menu(void);

int main(void){
int iVal;
double dVal;
welcome();
printTitle();
double grandtotal = 1234.57;
printFooter(grandtotal);
flushKeyboard();
pause();
getInt();
int lowerLimit = 10;
int upperLimit = 20;
getIntLimited(lowerLimit, upperLimit);

return 0;
}


//code your functions here:

void welcome(void)
{
printf("---=== Grocery Inventory System ===---");
printf("\n");
return;
}

void printTitle(void)
{
printf("Row |SKU| Name      | Price |Taxed| Qty | Min | Total   |Atn\n");
printf("----+---+---------------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-------------|---");
printf("\n");
return;
}

void printFooter(double grandTotal)
{
printf("--------------------------------------------------+-----------------");
printf("\n");

if (grandTotal > 0) {
printf("                                     Grand Total: | %12.2lf", grandTotal);
    }
                        return;
}


void flushKeyboard(void)
{
int read;

while (( read = getchar()) != '\n')
return;
}

void pause(void)
{
printf("Press <ENTER> to continue...");
flushKeyboard();
return;
}

int getInt(void)
{
int Value;
char NL = 'x';

while (NL != '\n') {
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d%c", &Value, &NL);

if (NL != '\n') {
    flushKeyboard();
    printf("Invalid integer, please try again:");
    scanf("%d%c", &Value, &NL);
    }

else {
    printf("You entered: %d\n", Value);
}
}
return Value;
}

int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)
{
int limit;
do {
    limit = getInt();

    if(lowerLimit > limit || limit > upperLimit) {
        printf("Invalid value, %d < %d < %d: ", lowerLimit, limit, upperLimit);
    }
}

    while(lowerLimit < limit && limit < upperLimit);
return limit;

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that displays that function alone. Nobody should have to sift through 50 lines of irrelevant code just to help you with that one function.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think it is more than 50

Comment: @SagarV - I was being generous

Comment: Sorry, I provided the entire code because a previous question I had involved some users stating that I should provide the full code even if they had no relevance to the function, so that's why I had provided my entire code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems here. The purpose of the `flushKeyboard()` function seems to be to clear the input stream, but as written it enters the loop and `return`s from the function immediately. Also, the `getchar()` function can return `EOF`, for example if the user signals it from the keyboard, but possibly more importantly, `EOF` is returned if there is an error in `getchar()`. If this happens in a loop that does not check for `EOF`, the result is an infinite loop.

```
while (( read = getchar()) != '\n')
return;
```

The above lines need to change to:

```
while (( read = getchar()) != '\n' && read != EOF) {
    continue;
}
return;
```

Additionally, this loop to clear the input stream should only be called when there are characters in the input stream to clear; otherwise `getchar()` will block, waiting for input. So, the call to `flushKeyboard()` after the line:

```
printFooter(grandtotal);
```

needs to be removed. And while we are here, the following `getInt()` seems to serve no purpose other than to confuse the user about input; this should also be removed.

In the `getInt()` function, the second call to `scanf()` needs to be removed. Only a prompt for more input is needed here, as `scanf()` will be called again when the loop continues. And the code that displays the entered value can be moved outside of the loop, before the `return` statement.

With these changes, and a few added newlines to clean up the display, the code seems to work. I am not convinced that the conditions in `getIntLimited()` function exactly as expected. As written, if the user enters either `lowerLimit` or `upperLimit`, the input is accepted and the function exits. If the user enters a number outside of this range, the function prints the error message, and exits. If the user enters a number inside the range, the function continues asking for a new integer.

Here is a modified version of the original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//tools
void welcome(void);
void printTitle(void);
void printFooter(double gTotal);
void flushKeyboard(void);
void pause(void);
int getInt(void);
double getDouble(void);
int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit);
double getDoubleLimited(double lowerLimit, double upperLimit);

//app interface
int yes(void);
void GroceryInventorySystem(void);
int menu(void);

int main(void){
int iVal;
double dVal;
    welcome();
    printTitle();
    double grandtotal = 1234.57;
    printFooter(grandtotal);
    pause();
    int lowerLimit = 10;
    int upperLimit = 20;
    getIntLimited(lowerLimit, upperLimit);

    return 0;
}


//code your functions here:

void welcome(void)
{
    printf("---=== Grocery Inventory System ===---");
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

void printTitle(void)
{
    printf("Row |SKU| Name      | Price |Taxed| Qty | Min | Total   |Atn\n");
    printf("----+---+---------------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-------------|---");
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

void printFooter(double grandTotal)
{
    printf("--------------------------------------------------+-----------------");
    printf("\n");

    if (grandTotal > 0) {
        printf("                                     Grand Total: | %12.2lf\n", grandTotal);
    }
    return;
}


void flushKeyboard(void)
{
    int read;

    while (( read = getchar()) != '\n' && read != EOF) {
        continue;
    }
    return;
}

void pause(void)
{
    printf("Press <ENTER> to continue...");
    flushKeyboard();
    return;
}

int getInt(void)
{
    int Value;
    char NL = 'x';

    while (NL != '\n') {
        printf("Enter an integer: ");
        scanf("%d%c", &Value, &NL);

        if (NL != '\n') {
            flushKeyboard();
            printf("Invalid integer, please try again:\n");
        }
    }

    printf("You entered: %d\n", Value);

    return Value;
}

int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)
{
    int limit;
    do {
        limit = getInt();
        if(lowerLimit > limit || limit > upperLimit) {
            printf("Invalid value, %d < %d < %d:\n", lowerLimit, limit, upperLimit);
        }
    } while(lowerLimit < limit && limit < upperLimit);

    return limit;
}
```

### Update

Here is a modification of the error logic in `getIntLimited()` that prompts the user to enter input again until the input is in range. You may want to adjust the error message:

```
int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)
{
    int limit;
    do {
        limit = getInt();
        if(limit < lowerLimit || upperLimit < limit) {
            printf("Invalid value, %d < %d < %d:\n", lowerLimit, limit, upperLimit);
        }
    } while(limit < lowerLimit || upperLimit < limit);

    return limit;
}
```

Here is an improvement to the `getInt()` function that is both more concise, and provides nicer input prompts. Note that I changed the initialization of `NL` to `'\0'`, in place of `'x'`. Not that important, but the null character is not to be expected in any user input.

```
int getInt(void)
{
    int Value;
    char NL = '\0';

    printf("Enter an integer: ");    
    while (scanf("%d%c", &Value, &NL) != 2 || NL != '\n') {
        flushKeyboard();
        printf("Invalid integer, please try again:\n");
    }

    printf("You entered: %d\n", Value);

    return Value;
}
```

Comment: I did leave my scanf statement for invalid integer, so that a user may continue to attempt to enter a valid integer, but it seems that the while statement also loops asking the user to enter an integer. Is there any way to have the while loop stop functioning after the user has input an invalid integer?

Comment: I was actually referring to the function getInt where every invalid integer following the initial invalid integer will produce the output:

    `Enter an integer: Invalid integer, please try again:`

But your update has helped with the getIntLimited function properly looping until the user inputs something within the parameters.

Comment: It's because the current output will have enter an integer next to the error message, which is unnecessary. I'll try to see if I can fix it, but thank you for all your help.

Comment: I added an improved `getInt()` function; when you have everything running, you should consider posting at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There people will go over your working code more closely, with suggestions about improvements and style.